# int32 len = va_args(va, int32) gives very large value on x86_64 GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, x86-64, variadic-functions

```
void AppBuf(message_id_type msgID, int32 numPairs, va_list va)

{
int32 len = va_args(va, int32);
....
}
```

The above piece of code runs perfectly fine on windows (32 and 64 bit) and also on linux 32 bit compiler. 
Value of 'len' comes out to 10 for all the above.

But on linux 64 bit (x86_64 GNU/Linux) I am getting a very large value for `len` (`50462976`), which messes up  the rest of the code and end ups in a crash.

I had read that something has changed in linux 64 bit compilers with respect to `va_lists` but I was not able to understand the change and so I was not able to fix my issue.

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Sunny

Ok, here are the details of the whole code leading upto this point: 
Could someone please help with this? Thanks in advance.

**Call Stack:**

AppendBuffers(int msgID=0x00000001, int numPairs=0x00000001, char * va=0x0007fcb0) **{NOTE: this is where the problem is occuring as mentioned above (length = very large)}**

LogMsg(int msgID=0x00000001, int numPairs=0x00000001, char * arguments=0x0007fcb0)

LogMsgBuffersV(int msgID=0x00000001, int numPairs=0x00000001, char * arguments=0x0007fcb0)

LogMsgBuffersV(int msgID=0x00000001, int numPairs=0x00000001, char * arguments=0x0007fcb0)

LogMsgBuffers(int msgID=0x00000001, int numPairs=0x00000001, ...)

**Actual code:**

```
void LogMsgBuffers(message_id_type msgID, int32 numPairs, ...)
{

    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, numPairs);

    filter_status_type msgStatus = FilterMsg(msgID);

    if (msgStatus == FILTER_ACCEPT)
    {
        LogMsg(msgID, numPairs, arguments);
    }

    if ((_parentLogger != NULL) && (_oAppenderInheritance))
    {
        //Pass the msg to the parent
        _parentLogger->LogMsgBuffersV(msgID, numPairs, arguments);
    }

    return;
}

void LogMsgBuffersV(message_id_type msgID, int32 numPairs, va_list arguments)
{

    filter_status_type msgStatus = FilterMsg(msgID);

    if (msgStatus == FILTER_ACCEPT)
    {
        //Log msg to the current node
        LogMsg(msgID, numPairs, arguments);
    }

    if ((_parentLogger != NULL) && (_oAppenderInheritance))
    {
        //Pass the msg to the parent
        _parentLogger->LogMsgBuffersV(msgID, numPairs, arguments);

    }
    return;
}

void LogMsgBuffersV(message_id_type msgID, int32 numPairs, va_list arguments)
{
    filter_status_type msgStatus = FilterMsg(msgID);

    if (msgStatus == FILTER_ACCEPT)
    {
        //Log msg to the current node
        LogMsg(msgID, numPairs, arguments);
    }

    if ((_parentLogger != NULL) && (_oAppenderInheritance))
    {
        //Pass the msg to the parent
        _parentLogger->LogMsgBuffersV(msgID, numPairs, arguments);

    }
    return;
}

void LogMsg(message_id_type msgID, int32 numPairs, va_list arguments)
{
    uint32 i;

    for (i = 0; i < _pOwnAppenderVec.size(); i++)
    {
        LoggerAppender *appender = _pOwnAppenderVec[i];
        appender->AppendBuffers(msgID, numPairs, arguments);
    }
    return;
}

void AppendBuffers(message_id_type msgID, int32 numPairs, va_list va)
        {

            for (int32 i = 0; i < numPairs; i++)
            {
                int32 length = va_arg(va, int32);
                uint8* buffer = va_arg(va, uint8*);

                int32 jj;
                for (jj = 10; jj < length; jj += 10)
                {
                    AppendStringA(0, "  %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[7], buffer[8], buffer[9]);
                    buffer += 10;
                }

                uint8 remainderbuf[10];
                uint32 remainder = length - (jj - 10);
                if (remainder > 0 && remainder <= 10)
                {
                    oscl_memcpy(remainderbuf, buffer, remainder);
                    oscl_memset(remainderbuf + remainder, 0, 10 - remainder);
                    buffer = remainderbuf;
                    AppendStringA(0, "  %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x", buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[3], buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[7], buffer[8], buffer[9]);
                }
            }
            va_end(va);
        }
```

Comment: How do you call the above code?

Comment: May it be that the calling code populates the list incorrectly on that specific configuration? For example, it might pass non-POD types.

Comment: Don't use `va_list`. If you need variadic arguments, use variadic templates, generated overloads or some other type-safe method.

Comment: There's no apparent problem in the code you show. It's hard to tell because it doesn't compile. Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have added details with respect to the code leading upto the problem. Could someone please help with this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

AFACIT, `va_args` is not a standard function. In fact, Google is turning up this question as one of its top answers, besides `__VA_ARGS__` macros.

There's in fact no standard way to determine how many `va_arg` arguments are in a given `va_list`, and [the  GCC page](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Argument-Macros.html) doesn't list any method either.